# Cross-compiling Valgrind for ARM

Tags: cross-compiling, valgrind

I need to cross-compile VALGRIND to run on Freescale i.MX278 (ARM 9) running Linux. I have the tool chain provided by Freescale itself.

I have already set the PATH variable to tool chain path. I'm using following command further:

```
$ export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-
$ export CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc
$ export CPP=${CROSS_COMPILE}cpp
$ export CXX=${CROSS_COMPILE}g++
$ export LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}ld
$ export AR=${CROSS_COMPILE}ar

$ ./configure --target=arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi \
              --host=armv7-fsl-linux-gnueabi \
              --prefix=/opt/valgrind \
              CFLAGS=-static
```

It passes the `./configure` but fails on `make` with following error:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-marm’
```

Answer (score 19):

First run the below command to make a change in the configure file

```
sed -i -e "s#armv7#arm#g" configure
```

Then run the configure option.

It will be cross-compiled successfully.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and tried your solution but still got the same error.  My configure: `./configure --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --host=armv7-none-linux-gnueabi`. Any other way to fix this ?

Comment: what is the version of valgrind you are trying to compile?

Comment: I'm using the last version of valgrind, which is valgrind-3.13.0.

Comment: what is the toolchain you are using is it arm-none-linux-gnueabi or armv7-none-linux-gnueabi ?

Comment: I'm using arm-none-linux-gnueabi.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159556/discussion-between-ashwanth-selvam-and-toan-tran).

Comment: hi can you send me the output of the below command echo $PATH
Also attach your entire configure log
I think you did not export your toolchain

Comment: hi ashwanth, please refer to my question for the updated situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426961/unable-to-cross-compile-valgrind-for-arm. Please take a look if you have spare time

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party but for any one else coming here, it seems the valgrind build system differ between setting the environment variables in the shell and passing them as arguments to `configure`. Try:

```
$ export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-
$ ./configure --target=arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi \
              --host=armv7-fsl-linux-gnueabi \
              --prefix=/opt/valgrind \
              CFLAGS=-static \
              CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc \
              CPP=${CROSS_COMPILE}cpp \
              CXX=${CROSS_COMPILE}g++ \
              LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}ld \
              AR=${CROSS_COMPILE}ar
```

Comment: I am trying to cross compile valgrind 3.17. I have fixed the error `"for a supported CPU... no (arm)"` error by refereeing the comments in this thread. After that I am getting `"checking for a supported OS... no (none)"` error. The command I ran is `"./configure --host=arm-linux-"`.  we need to run valgrind on "armv6k" architecture. Can you guide to address the error.